# How do I invest in NYSE outside US?

Tags: stocks, turkey

I want to invest in NYSE. Is it possible to buy stocks traded in NYSE as a non-citizen and non-resident?

**EDIT:** I am from Turkey

Comment: Please add a country, a member familiar with the country in question might help.

Comment: Do some online searching. Here is a good start: http://www.selectabroker.com/Turkey/

Comment: selectbroker.com returns results that are related to Turkey, actually.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your bank, not location.

Additionally, there are many different ways to invest in the NYSE - or did you mean in stocks listed on the NYSE?

Either way, your bank needs to allow you to do so.

You can buy an ETF to participate for example in the SP500.